# How to remove username from sorcery app user attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorcery

I'm using sorcery for authentication on a rails app and I was wondering how to remove the username from the User model. I am successfully using the email address for login, but I still see this on each user in the database `username: nil`

How do I get rid of that? What should the migration look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
remove_column :users, :username
```